# how to fetch data from key value pair in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging, try-catch

I am using rails on the backend and vue.js on the front end. I am trying to print the error in case there is any. Under the `.catch`  I have got the error as below but cannot fetch the message from it. Kindly help me resolve it.

```
.catch(function (error) {
 debugger
});
```

In the console, if I try `error.response.data.error` this returns `'{:message=>"Amount is less than the minimum value"}'` I am not able to figure out how I can fetch just the message.

[image]

[image]

Error Answer

[image]

Comment: Can't you do `error.response.data.error.message`? Also, do you mind sharing a screenshot of the payload if that way doesn't work?

Comment: @kissu error.response.data.error.message returns undefined

Comment: Also, do you mind sharing a screenshot of the payload if that way doesn't work?

Comment: @kissu attached

Comment: There is no `message` here.

Comment: please check in the question

Comment: I can't see any `error.response.data.error` tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your baclend is not serializing object correctly. So message is a part of a string instead of JSON property. If you don't want to change that you can use

```
const message = error.response.data.error.substring(
    str.indexOf('"') + 1, 
    str.lastIndexOf('"')
);
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined I am getting this error. Please check the screenshot in the question section

Comment: So I can't see the editing answer

Comment: My answet should say `error.response.data.error.substring` instead of `str.substring` now